# How can I use an async loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How can I write a loop and send a request to the server so that the next request is performed after receiving the response in the previous request?

I want the requests to be sent in order and the results to be displayed in order:

```
for (item of [1,2,3]){
  fetch(`http://test.com/users/${item}`).then((res)=>{
     console.log(res.id) // I want the next request, to be send after received this reponse
  }) 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use await flag. so await fetch(...) should do it

```js
async function example() {
  for (item of [1, 2, 3]) {
    let res = await fetch(`http://test.com/users/${item}`);
    console.log(res.id); // I want the next request, to be send after received this reponse
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You don't really need the `.then()`; the `console.log()` can go on the line after `await` if you save the value returned to a variable.

Comment: Sure, I mean it's not *wrong* but I've seen so many questions here where people get themselves tied up in knots by mixing `async/await` with `.then()` callbacks.

Comment: simple is beautiful, less is more. It's all about readability and maintainability.  I do appreciate the pointers, @Pointy

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.then()`, you should use `await`, which works inside `for`, `while` and `do..while` loops (also, you should probably wrap the `fetch` calls in a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)):

```js
function fakeFetch(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ id: url })
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function fetchItems() {
  for (let item of [1,2,3]){
    console.log(`Fetching ${ item }...`)
    
    try {
      const res = await fakeFetch(`http://test.com/users/${ item }`)

      console.log(res.id)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Item ${ item } error:`, err)
    }
  }
}

fetchItems()
```

Note this won't work for Array methods that require a callback such as  `forEach`, `map`, `reduce` or `filter`.

The drawback of this approach is that it takes longer than resolving the promises (requests) in parallel, as you wait for one to resolve before making the next request. Instead, you might want to consider using [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled):

```js
function fakeFetch(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ id: url })
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function fetchItems() {
  const promises = [1,2,3].map((item) => {
    console.log(`Fetching ${ item }...`)
    
    return fakeFetch(`http://test.com/users/${ item }`)  
  })
  
  const items = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
  
  console.log(items)
}

fetchItems()
```

Comment: Your remark about `Promise.allSettled` makes no sense, as the OP explicitly asks to "*send a request to the server so that the next request is performed after receiving the response in the previous request*"

Comment: @Bergi the OP also explicitly says _"I want the requests to be sent in order and the results to be displayed in order"_, which still holds true for the alternative I provided. It's not totally clear to me if the part you cite is a requirement or an assumption based on the actual requirement I'm citing. That's why I'm providing both answers. Also, some other users other than the OP will eventually come across this post, so having different alternatives is usually useful and productive (no need for an additional very similar question).

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, I also tested this way:

```js
const fetchMethod = (item)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
       resolve (fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${item}`))
    }, item === 1 ? 5000 : 1000);
  })
}

async function example() {
  for (item of [1, 2, 3]) {
    let res = await fetchMethod(item)
    let res2 = await res.json()
    console.log(res2);
  }
}

example();
```